# PostgreSQL: Get elapsed amount between integers

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to get the difference between the first start_time and the last stop_time in the table. But I can't seem to get this done in one query. Can somebody help me? This is some sample data:

```
    start_time     |     stop_time
-------------------+-------------------
 1398871312.769668 | 1398871312.769676
 1398871312.771368 | 1398871312.771429
 1398871312.771471 | 1398871312.771476
 1398871312.771494 | 1398871312.771543
 1398871312.781109 | 1398871312.781115
 1398871312.781150 | 1398871312.781154
 1398871312.781233 | 1398871312.781282
 1398871312.992759 | 1398871312.992765
 1398871312.992795 | 1398871312.992798
 1398871312.992832 | 1398871312.992881
   1398871313.3387 |   1398871313.3399
   1398871313.3435 |   1398871313.3440
   1398871313.3703 |   1398871313.3745
 1398871313.203462 | 1398871313.203469
 1398871313.203497 | 1398871313.203501
 1398871313.203560 | 1398871313.203600
 1398871313.214120 | 1398871313.214127
 1398871313.214153 | 1398871313.214158
 1398871313.214177 | 1398871313.214192
 1398871313.214208 | 1398871313.214248
 1398871313.415027 | 1398871313.415035
 1398871313.415136 | 1398871313.415140
 1398871313.415218 | 1398871313.415226
 1398871313.415252 | 1398871313.415265
 1398871313.415290 | 1398871313.415298
 1398871313.415332 | 1398871313.415339
 1398871313.415350 | 1398871313.415362
 1398871314.144867 | 1398871314.144886
 1398871314.144896 | 1398871314.144901
 1398871314.144906 | 1398871314.144912
 1398871314.144918 | 1398871314.144923
 1398871314.144927 | 1398871314.144931
 1398871314.144935 | 1398871314.144939
 1398871314.144965 | 1398871314.144974
 1398871314.145055 | 1398871314.145060
 1398871314.145138 | 1398871314.145146
 1398871314.145152 | 1398871314.145158
 1398871314.145166 | 1398871314.145173
 1398871314.145211 | 1398871314.145215
 1398871314.145235 | 1398871314.145243
 1398871314.145247 | 1398871314.145252
 1398871314.145262 | 1398871314.145267
 1398871314.145307 | 1398871314.145314
 1398871314.145547 | 1398871314.145551
 1398871314.145563 | 1398871314.145571
 1398871314.145576 | 1398871314.145581
 1398871314.145586 | 1398871314.145590
 1398871314.145600 | 1398871314.145606
 1398871314.145611 | 1398871314.145618
 1398871314.145623 | 1398871314.145627
 1398871314.145634 | 1398871314.145641
 1398871314.145999 | 1398871314.146003
 1398871314.146014 | 1398871314.146022
 1398871314.146026 | 1398871314.146033
 1398871314.146043 | 1398871314.146050
 1398871314.146140 | 1398871314.146145
 1398871314.146160 | 1398871314.146168
 1398871314.146178 | 1398871314.146185
```

So I want the difference between 1398871312 and 1398871314, in one query. Is this possible? Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
select max(stop_time) - min(start_time)
from Table1
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks! Can't believe I didn't see that.